The most hassle free way to integrate social logins to a react native bare expo environment
the official google login library for react native requires a lot of platform specific configuration
I saw that the official library requires platform specific configuration at least with google login and I was wondering if using say passport or other alternative could allow for an easier setup specifically with react native with a bare expo environment?

Well, I have used google sign in one of my application with EXPO managed environment. All I had to do is develop the project in development mode and not EXPO GO.
